# C# don't understand calling methods. object oriented programming

Tags: c#

I've just started object oriented programming and I don't quite understand how to call another method. I wanted to calculate the percentage increase and then put out the resulting overall price. This would be done by calling the method to do the working out then returning the value to the other method. However I'm unsure about how to cross over between methods.

Could someone please explain how I'm meant to do this? Preferably not just giving the answer so I can fully understand what's happening.

p.s. this piece of code is in a class called `RetailPricing`. As I've copied and pasted it, it doesn't look like it's all formatted properly (I understand how to call this class to the main program)

```
namespace week7exercise2
{
    class RetailPricing
    {
        public void CalculateRetailPrice()
        {
            double inputcost;
            double inputpercent;
            string inputitemcost;
            string inputmarkup;

            Console.Write("Please Input The Cost Of The Item: ");
            inputitemcost = Console.ReadLine();
            inputcost = double.Parse(inputitemcost);

            Console.Write("Please Input The Markup Percentage: ");
            inputmarkup = Console.ReadLine();
            inputpercent = double.Parse(inputmarkup);

            Console.Write("Your Retail Price Is: " + newprice);
        }

        public double sum(double MarkUpPercentage, double overallprice, double newprice)
        {            
            MarkUpPercentage = inputpercent + 100;
            overallprice = MarkUpPercentage / 100;
            newprice = inputcost * overallprice;
            return newprice;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is that you want to call a function to perform some calculations.

*Before your last line*:

```
Console.Write("Your Retail Price Is: " + newprice);
```

What you need to do is call your function for calculating price and it'll return the price after calculating it. So simply do:

```
double newprice = sum(inputpercent,inputcost)
```

And change your sum function to:

```
public double sum(double MarkUpPercentage, double overallprice)
    {            
        MarkUpPercentage = inputpercent + 100;
        overallprice = MarkUpPercentage / 100;
        double newprice = inputcost * overallprice;
        return newprice;
    }
```